# How to create multi-branch project with Jenkins DSL plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-job-dsl

Is it possible to create multi-branch project with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin?

I want to define Groovy DSL configuration in Jenkins file under Git branch.
I'd like to have similar UI as with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin, e.g.:

- job-name(multi-branch DSL project - not sure it exists)

  - master (folder)

    - job 1 from master DSL
    - job 2 from master DSL
  - feature/branch1 (folder)

    - job 1 from feature/branch1 DSL
    - job 2 from feature/branch1 DSL

Comment: This blog post describes how to create a multi-branch setup with Job DSL Plugin: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/generated-jenkins-jobs-and-automatic-branch-merging-for-feature-branches/. The examples are for Mercurial, but should be easy to adapt to Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tracked a [JENKINS-31671](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31671). There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/671) and I hope to get this merged for the next release.

In the meantime you could use a custom build of the Job DSL plugin, built from the pull request. Or you can use a [configure block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to adapt the job config XML to the multibranch plugin. There is an [example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block#configure-matrix-job) that shows how to change the project type. That has to be adapted to the multibranch plugin.

```
job('example') {
  configure { project ->
    project.name = 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject'

    // adapt the XML to the multibranch project type
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not trying to configure multibranch project (I mean regular Multibranch project) from DSL. I'd want to have something like branch job (from Multibranch plugin), but acting as a folder (from Cloudbees Folder plugin), so that I can create a job in this folder. The same is implemented in Workflow plugin new feature - workflow multibranching . You just need to specify repository and it scans branches for Jenkins file, then creates workflow job for each branch.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. You want to have a multibranch project, but not using the workflow-multibranch plugin? Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I wan't to have similar functionality in Job DSL plugin.

Comment: that's not what I exactly looked for, but it can solve my problem. Thanks!